# Dim a 110 Light using 5v PWM with no ZC

Tags: light, dimming

I was wondering if anyone has any ideas of a way I could Dim a 110v Halogen light with the use of 5V PWM, or with 0-24v control.

My controller, has the basic (designed) 0-24v control. It also has the ability to be used for 0-5v PWM by using the connection to the gate.

I have seen Light Dimmers for 110v AC lamps, and using an Arduino, however most of them want Zero Cross, which my controller (TC420) cant do. So I need a way to dim 110v AC, with just PWM, or 0-12v.

I seen talks of using SSRs, to do this, but again the Zero Cross comes up, and I am not sure I can zero cross the controller.

Comment: Please edit your question to show a schematic of what you've got and a link to the datasheet for your TC420 controller. There's a button for the built-in schematic tool on the editor toolbar. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: I'm not sure of what you mean by a schematic of what I got? 

There sadly is no such datasheet, its a Chinese microcontroller, no Datasheet exists. Closest I would have is a 3rd party site, on the product. https://www.tc420.net/

From that, I did discover everything is PWM however, so I can go from the gate for 5v pwm, or use up to 24v pwm, but in all cases its PWM.

Answer (score 0):

If you search online you can find ready made dimmer control modules that can take in a PWM signal and control an AC powered light. The modules I saw take care of the necessary zero cross detection and phase control on the module.

Search for "PWM AC Voltage Dimmer 50/60Hz 80-240VAC"  at large online retailer to find this.

As with anything AC mains connected, module or self built, use much care for safety and caution to avoid injury and property damage.